# Mixed Content , Content-Security-Policy and hash-source

Tags: content-security-policy, mixed-content

I'd like to open an HTTP Iframe inside an HTTPS page. Of course this is not normally possible as it will trigger an 'mixed-content' violation.

Is there any way to by-pass a mixed content block using "Content-Security-Policy" and hash sources ?

Example:

- `http://mysite/my-frame.html` has an sha-256 hash of `sha256-xxxyyy....zzz`
- `https://mysite/index.html` will be served with a `Content-Security-Policy` header as follow (or inlines an equivalente `<meta>` tag)  as long as CORS headers:

  - `Content-Security-Policy: frame-src sha256-xxxxyyyy....zzz`
- `https://mysite/index.html` includes an `<iframe src='http://mysite/my-frame.html'>`

Will this work ? Is there any other method to make this possible.

*note*: No `upgrade-insecure-requests` will not work because the page is a navigational request AND the frame HAS to be served from HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to bypass the security block on modern browsers (starting from Firefox 23, Chrome 14, IE9)

> Thankfully, most modern browsers block this type of dangerous content
>   by default

ref: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content#mixed-content-types--security-threats-associated

Answer (score 0):

What if the server sets the csp `child-src` to `http://mysite/my-frame.html`? As I read the definitions it should work.

> child-src lists the URLs for workers and embedded frame contents. For example: child-src https://youtube.com would enable embedding videos from YouTube but not from other origins. Use this in place of the deprecated frame-src directive.
>
> https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/